# Need a word that describes an assembly of related types of data

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a word that would describe a kind of "container" or a "repository" that holds related objects of various data types.

Here's a rough outline of the scenario how that "container" is used.

1. User can create entities of various types - it could be a form, a description of person or anything you can come up with
2. User can sell all objects he creates via "marketplace" by exporting them with the help of a "container", meaning that a container can be purchased and it will hold various types of entities

Essentially, a "container" is a bin that can hold entities of multiple types. "Marketplace" **only** accepts containers, and cannot be used to sell entities themselves.

I like the word "**cabinet**" to describe it, how does that sound to you?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example sentence this must be used in?

Comment: No, I am looking for global term for it.

Comment: How about a Dopp kit? https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Dopp+kit

Comment: Unfortunately, [naming stuff is off-topic here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You can sometimes ask about the implications or history of a particular name, but "what should I name X" is on the wrong side of good-subjective. You should look at various synonyms of [container](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/container?s=t) or [box](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/box?s=t) and see what you like, then come back and ask a specific question if you have one. (That said, "cabinet" seems off, since you want to (figuratively) move stuff around in your container.)

Answer (score 1):

[Set](http://www.storyofmathematics.com/glossary.html#S): a collection of distinct objects or numbers, without regard to their order, considered as an object in its own right

Answer (score 0):

**Portfolio**

> a range of products or services offered by an organization, especially when considered as a business asset.

"an unrivaled portfolio of quality brands"

[Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=portfolio)

Comment: Bracket or category do not reflect the nature of it. You put various objects in that container and offer the whole package for sale.

Comment: "Bundle" is another word that came to mind.

Comment: Are we talking of a physical container or like a cataloging term? I've taken your question like your categorizing things into something like a computer folder.

Comment: No, it is a logical entity. Yes, same idea as folder, as it can contain photos, text files and so on. Only I don't like the idea of selling and buying "folders". There got to be a better word for it.

Answer (score 0):

'kit bag': it's an old word for backpack. It's got the potential to be universal because users will understand either 'kit' or 'bag'.

Comment: Kit bag: "a rectangular canvas bag, used especially for carrying a soldier's clothes and personal possessions." Source: https://www.google.com/search?q=kit+bag+definition

Comment: Look at it from e-commerce perspective. "I am offering for sale a kitbag containing video, images and PDF". Doesn't sound great.

Answer (score 0):

Pack

This conveys the idea of backpack (to carry away items).

Answer (score 0):

**Cart**

Turn your market into a 'super'market and have carts.